# How to get the index with the key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, indexing, key

I have the key of a python dictionary and I want to get the corresponding index in the dictionary. Suppose I have the following dictionary,

```
d = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
```

Is there a combination of python functions so that I can get the index value of 1, given the key value 'b'?

```
d.??('b')
```

I know it can be achieved with a loop or lambda (with a loop embedded). Just thought there should be a more straightforward way.

Comment: What's wrong with `d['b']` ?

Comment: d['b'] will give you 20. But I actually want to get the position of the key in the dictionary which is 1. And I have the dictionary created as an ordered dictionary.

Comment: In dictionary, keys are unordered. So you could get any key while iterating the keys.

Comment: you can use ordereddict() from the collections package

Comment: If you have an ordered dict, then `d.keys().index(k)` should do it.

Comment: Yes Felix, it works! Thanks a lot. Start getting tunnel visioning. Time to go to bed to get refreshed. :)

Comment: @FelixKling What version of Python are using? When I tried to that code, I got the error `AttributeError: 'KeysView' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: @Seanny123  You didn't mention what version of Python *you* are using. Presumably it is Python 3, see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/  So, `list(d.keys()).index(k)`. Though hopefully there is a better solution in Python 3, that doesn't require creating a list of all the keys...

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use OrderedDicts: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

```
>>> x = OrderedDict((("a", "1"), ("c", '3'), ("b", "2")))
>>> x["d"] = 4
>>> x.keys().index("d")
3
>>> x.keys().index("c")
1
```

For those using Python 3

```
>>> list(x.keys()).index("c")
1
```

Comment: Good solution but , im wondering the complexity of getting the index (might be O(n)) . can we get key-value pair by the index value > or atleast key or value.

Comment: Also consider Pandas [`dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for this use-case, especially if you need to be able to drop items while the assigned index locations remain fixed (i.e. a dropped item creates a 'hole' in the data structure), or if you need to be able to have multiple items in the structure with the same "key" (obviously it is not a real key in such case).

Comment: The `.keys()` is optional btw. Just `list(x).index("c")` also works.

Comment: .keys().index(...) doesn't work at least for python3, so I used list(x).index("c") which is probably less efficient because it uses a list instead of an iterator, but it works

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries in python (<3.6) have no order. You could use a list of tuples as your data structure instead.

```
d = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
newd = [('a',10), ('b',20), ('c',30)]
```

Then this code could be used to find the locations of keys with a specific value

```
locations = [i for i, t in enumerate(newd) if t[0]=='b']

>>> [1]
```

Comment: Ur answer is correct but the complexity of serching or inserting is high . That is the reson ppl use dictionay , orderedDict is similar to hashtable in java .

Answer (score 3):

You can simply send the dictionary to `list` and then you can select the index of the item you are looking for.

```
DictTest = {
    '4000':{},
    '4001':{},
    '4002':{},
    '4003':{},
    '5000':{},
}

print(list(DictTest).index('4000'))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, in Python 2 there is no straightforward way because dictionaries in that version do not have a set ordering (you need Python 3.6 or newer for that, 3.7 if it is not a cpython implementation).

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

In other words, the 'index' of `b` depends entirely on what was inserted into and deleted from the mapping before:

```
>>> map={}
>>> map['b']=1
>>> map
{'b': 1}
>>> map['a']=1
>>> map
{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
>>> map['c']=1
>>> map
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}
```

As of Python 2.7, you could use the [`collections.OrderedDict()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead, if insertion order is important to your application.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this: Since python 3.7, dictionary iteration order is now guaranteed to be in order of insertion.

Comment: @Banana: yes, but the question _here_ is tagged with Python 2.7, which never got the new dictionary implementation.

Comment: question is tagged as both `python` and `python-2.7`, and the words "python 2.7" are not directly specified anywhere in the question, therefore @Banana's comment is valid

Comment: @Fnord: using the 2.7 tag **makes the question specific to 2.7**; at the time this answer was written, to get python 3.x answers we'd use the [tag:python-3.x] tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Creating dictionary
animals = {"Cat" : "Pat", "Dog" : "Pat", "Tiger" : "Wild"}

#Convert dictionary to list (array)
keys = list(animals)

#Printing 1st dictionary key by index
print(keys[0])

#Done :)
```

Comment: _"thanks to Se7enstars"_? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

Convert your dict into a list first

```
d = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
print(list(d.values())[1])
# OUTPUT: 20
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and consider whether you contribute information that is not already in existing answers, before adding an answer to a years-old question.