# How to do list comprehension on a list of dictionaries without returning values in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to perform list comprehension on a list of dictionaries. Using an example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538885/how-to-get-the-index-with-the-key-in-a-dictionary), works, but returns a list of lists. This is the code I am using:

```
transaction_types=[[v for k,v in t.items() if 'transaction_type' in k] for t in all_transactions].
```

Which would return a list as such: [['deposit'], ['withdrawal'], ['withdrawal'], ['withdrawal'], ['deposit'], ['closed account']]

How can I do the same, but without returning the values inside of a list? The result would look like so: ['deposit', 'withdrawal', 'withdrawal', 'withdrawal', 'deposit', 'closed account'].

Dropping the list inside of the list comprehension like so:

```
transaction_types=[[v for k,v in t.items() if 'transaction_type' in k] for t in all_transactions].
```

just returns the first value of the dictionary * the number of dictionaries. E.g. :
[['deposit'], ['deposit'], ['deposit'], ['deposit'], ['deposit'], ['deposit']]

Comment: Use a normal loop and append to a list.

Comment: I think you can use "get" with an additional argument for handling key-not-found case.

Comment: @MarkLavin can you point to any examples?

Comment: Can you show an example of the dictionary *t* ?

Comment: "Dropping the list inside of the list comprehension like so"--how is transaction_type different from the original expression?  Try `transaction_types=[v for t in all_transactions for k,v in t.items() if 'transaction_type' in k]`

Comment: @JCaesar There's another if statement in the list comprehension that searches for a bank account number from a list of bank accounts. The list of dictionaries is a flattened JSON. The data is confidential so I can't really post exact information.

Comment: @DarrylG your solution worked. Thanks! If you add an answer I can choose yours as the solution.

Comment: @Nate--added comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using technique from: [How to convert a nested loop to a list comprehension in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945761/how-to-convert-a-nested-loop-to-a-list-comprehension-in-python) we have the following two equivalent solutions.

**List Comprehension**

```
 transaction_types=[v for t in all_transactions for k,v in t.items() if 'transaction_type' in k]
```

**Double For Loop**

```
transaction_types = []
for t in all_transactions:
    for k, v in t.items():
        if 'transaction_type' in k:
            transaction_types.append(v)
```